# g(x) = sum of f(x)s from 1 to x in Geogebra

Tags: geogebra

I was trying to draw a graph g which adds every value of f(x)=-4242.3333333333 x+133323+4242.3333333333 for every x so like for 3 it would be g(3) = f(1) + f(2) + f(3).

```
f(x) = -4242.3333333333x + 133323 + 4242.3333333333
```

```
g(3) = f(1) + f(2) + f(3)
```

I tried **g(x) = Sum(f(k),k,1,x)** vut that didn't work, and now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed Sequence function.

```
Sum(Sequence(f(k),k,1,n))
```

[image]